# How to make Gui Buttons always Active on Screen or controls wont disappear when Executed

Tags: autohotkey

Problem : when i pressed UI button
the GUI will disappear or destroyed.

so basically what I'm trying achieve is.
every time i click the UI buttons it will execute the shortcut assigned.
and I want a rule that UI buttons wont disappear from screen unless I click [ X ] button

[UI Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9dRz.png)

Here's a AHK code ( its for photoshop )

```
alt & d::
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, XposA, YposA
XposA-=+0
YposA-=+0

gui, blend_custom_layer:destroy
gui, blend_custom:Submit,nohide
Gui, blend_custom_layer: Font, s9,Segoe UI
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Color, EEAA99


;-------- UI

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x0 y0 w20 h20 BackgroundTrans gclosewanrmenu, ✘
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y0 w200 h20  BackgroundTrans gnormal_blend_layer_command, Normal
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x221 y0 w20 h20 BackgroundTrans gclosewanrmenu, ☰
            
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y20 w110 h20  BackgroundTrans gmultiply_blend_layer_command, Multiply
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x130 y20 w111 h20 BackgroundTrans gscreen_blend_layer_command, Screen

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y40 w110 h20 BackgroundTrans gdarken_blend_layer_command, Darken
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x130 y40 w111 h20 BackgroundTrans glighten_blend_layer_command, Lighten

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y60 w110 h20 BackgroundTrans gcolor_burn_blend_layer_command, Color Burn
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x130 y60 w111 h20 BackgroundTrans gcolor_dodge_blend_layer_command, Color Dodge

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y80 w110 h20 BackgroundTrans glinear_burn_blend_layer_command, Linear Burn
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x130 y80 w111 h20 BackgroundTrans glinear_dodge_blend_layer_command, Linear Dodge


Gui blend_custom_layer:+LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui blend_custom_layer:-Caption
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show, x%XposA% y%YposA% h500 w500, menus
return

;-------- Commands

closewanrmenu:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
return


normal_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
Return


multiply_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
sendinput {alt down}{shift down}{m down}
sendinput {alt up}{shift up}{m up}
return

screen_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{s down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{s up}
return

darken_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{k down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{k up}
Return

lighten_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{g down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{g up}
Return

color_burn_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{b down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{b up}
Return

color_dodge_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{d down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{d up}
Return

linear_burn_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{a down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{a up}
Return

linear_dodge_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
send {alt down}{shift down}{w down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{w up}
Return
```

if you have free spare of time can someone please edit the code for me
this is a template i got from another source and i have just edited some of it ( i really dont know what im doing , i am not a programmer )

Now hear me out i tried the following but failed
gui,submit,nohide ( command from ahk )

Attempt 1 ( this is not working )

```
normal_blend_layer_command:
gui,submit,nohide
send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
Return
```

Attempt 2 ( this one kinda works , the UI buttons wont hide from screen but i lost the functionality of executing the shortcut assigned to each buttons )

```
normal_blend_layer_command:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Submit,nohide
send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
normal_blend_layer_command:
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:Submit
    send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
    send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
    ; Uncomment next line if you want to show the gui after a delay
    ; Sleep, 300 
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show 
Return
```